# MIXED_ES Too many es are not es

Tags: email, phpmailer, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I sending emails using PHPMailer and SpamAssassin is tagging it

`*  3.3 MIXED_ES Too many es are not es`
What does it mean? What is "es"? How to fix?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have multiple "ě" and "é" in my e-mails, because in our language it's commonly used.

Comment: Hi, not jet. I am from the same country :-)

Answer (score 8):

Spamassassin errors are often unhelpful! [The source](https://github.com/apache/spamassassin/blob/c677914baa227ddddb954384afb124013d6f70b4/rulesrc/sandbox/billcole/24_mixed_es.cf) for that rule suggests it's to do with too many letter 'E's that are not "regular" letter Es, for example any of éèëêēĕėëẻěȅȇẹȩęḙḛềếễểḕḗệḝɇǝⱸ. It's to do with your content, not PHPmailer.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to fix it? Can help quoted-printable content or not?

Comment: It depends exactly how Spamassassin does the check - if it looks only at the raw, encoded message body, then quoted-printable will help, but if it decodes the body first, that won't help.

Comment: Yep. It’s a terrible rule.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the duplicate messages ( disable the test), you can add, somewhere at the top, in

/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf

```
meta __E_LIKE_LETTER  (0)
meta __LOWER_E  (0)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an error in Spam assassins rules as @Synchro says. We can't do anything with that until they remove that crapy code. I try to contact authors.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was adding this code before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<div style="display:none;">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Is your plaintext version of the email in a different language than your HTML content?

Like Synchro said, it is caused by different kind of E's using diacritics. If the mailing is recognized by SpamAssassin as being "English" and the HTML content is actually in another language that makes use a lot of those ES, it can result in this message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this Spamassassin rule activated because I generated email content in Russian which included the Russian е letter (yes, that is not e but е, totally different character, although almost identical with latin e) but email signature contained email address and a plain text link to a domain with latin e letter.